# Запятая в сложносочинненом предложении

Tags: синтаксис

Дождь прекратился и стало гораздо теплее. По каким правилам здесь отсутствует запятая? Ведь только второе предложение безличное. Мне кажется, что запятая все же нужна.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дождь прекратился, и стало гораздо теплее.

**Запятая не ставится:** 1) при наличии **общего элемента** (обстоятельства, предложения, вводного слов и др.); 2) в случае **однородных односоставных** предложений, которые можно приравнять к однородным членам. Здесь эти условия не соблюдены.

Сравнить: **К утру** дождь прекратился и стало гораздо теплее.